# Insert a word with sed into a text file

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a text file and I want to insert a word like **house** before every word that begins with a lower-case letter in a file, using sed. I've tried this but it's not working:

```
sed "s/(^[a-z]+| [a-z]+)/house (^[a-z]+| [a-z]+)/g" textfile.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this line, is it ok for you?

```
sed -r 's/\b[a-z]\w*\b/HOUSE &/g' file
```

with example:

```
kent$ echo "yes No yES NO y_e_s _no"|sed -r 's/\b[a-z]\w*\b/HOUSE &/g'
HOUSE yes No HOUSE yES NO HOUSE y_e_s _no
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIX friendly version:

```
sed -e 's/\([^[:alpha:]]\)\([a-z][[:alpha:]]*\)/\1house \2/g' 
    -e 's/^\([a-z]\)/house \1/' input
```